# Permissions not working in react native Expo standalone app (build)

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo

I am trying to get Location permissions in react native expo but failed to do so.
I searched a lot for it but couldn't find a proper solution.
the code snippet for Location permission is:

```js
 async componentDidMount(){
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Location Permission',
          'message': 'Allow App to use location of your device.' 
                     
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("got")
        this.setState({show:false});
      } else {
        console.log("failed")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error',err)
    }
    
    
  }
```

It shows the following error:

error [Error: Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity.]

I am using

"expo": "^25.0.0",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-25.0.0.tar.gz",

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Expo Permission API

```
const { status } = await Expo.Permissions.askAsync(Expo.Permissions.LOCATION);

if (status === 'granted') {
    const location = await Expo.Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
    });
    return location;
}
```

Comment: thank u for your reply. I tried it but cant get permissions

Comment: the conditions was false in my case

Comment: i'm glad it helped you